# How to read a .txt file inside a 7z folder using python?

Tags: python, 7zip, temporary-files, py7zr

I'm trying to print() the contents of a .txt file (called helloWorld.txt)  and this .txt file is inside a .7z folder.

The folder is called FolderWorld.7z

Here's what I've tried:

```
    import py7zr
    import io
    
    archive_path = 'FolderWorld.7z'
    mnf_file_path = 'helloWorld.txt'
    
    with py7zr.SevenZipFile(archive_path, mode='r') as z:
        with z.open(mnf_file_path, 'r') as mnf_file:
            mnf_content = mnf_file.read().decode()
            print(mnf_content)
```

but it says z has no attribute "open"

I tried creating then a temp directory to read the txt file, like that:

```
import py7zr
import tempfile

    
archive_path = 'FolderWorld.7z'
mnf_file_path = 'helloWorld.txt'

with py7zr.SevenZipFile(archive_path, mode='r') as z:
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmp_dir:
        z.extract(mnf_file_path, path=tmp_dir)
        
        extracted_file_path = tmp_dir + '/' + mnf_file_path
        with open(extracted_file_path, 'r') as mnf_file:
            mnf_content = mnf_file.read()
            print(mnf_content)
```

Still nothing (it says that path has too many attributes)

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [read()](https://py7zr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#py7zr.SevenZipFile.read) method of SevenZipFile object, which return a dict of BytesIO object of the target files.

```
import py7zr
import io

archive_path = 'FolderWorld.7z'
mnf_file_path = 'helloWorld.txt'

with py7zr.SevenZipFile(archive_path, mode='r') as z:
    mnf_content = z.read(mnf_file_path)[mnf_file_path].read().decode()
    print(mnf_content)
```